# Inherited Exception Property Not Being Handled in ResponseEntityExceptionHandler

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, inheritance, exception

I have a simple Spring Boot exception handler that handles REST controller's exceptions globally (see below).

```
@RestControllerAdvice(annotations = RestController.class)
@EnableWebMvc
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class MyCustomExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = { SomeCustomException.class })
    public ResponseEntity<Object> hanldeSomeCustomException(SomeCustomException ex) {
      // ...
    }
}
```

My `SomeCustomException` inherits another custom exception, e.g. `ParentCustomException`, that contains a property, say, `parentProperty` (private).

When an `Exception` is thrown, I catch it and throw a new `SomeCustomException` with this inherited property (`parentProperty`) set. I can see the value in this `SomeCustomException` object when it is thrown, along with a property that only belongs to `SomeCustomException`, e.g. `someCustomProperty`.

However, when the logic gets to the exception handling (`hanldeSomeCustomException()`), `ex` only contains value for `SomeCustomException.someCustomProperty` but not `ParentCustomException.parentProperty`.

Can somebody tell me why this is the case and how I can handle my `SomeCustomException` with value for `parentProperty`?

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code of `SomeCustomException`  and `ParentCustomException` you're talking about in your answer?

Comment: The issue was that up the stack (5 layers in some obscure catch block), someone was using an overloaded construction of `SomeCustomException` which was not calling the right `super()`, which in turn was not setting `parentProperty`. The code for those Exception classes wouldn't have helped figuring out the issue.

Comment: True that, that also means that this question was unsalvageable from the start. It's always helpful for potential answerers to show all code to be able to reproduce the problem. For more info you can check [mcve].

Comment: Understood. Writing up every possible catch block and rethrows throughout the code base would have made it very difficult to formulate the question in the first place. I just wanted to see if in case of Spring `Advice`, information is lost in inheritance (which would have defined OO principles).